# How to make remote desktop work in corporate network

Tags: internet, remote-desktop, proxy, firewall

my work network has most of the connections closed. I can surf web but cant access webmail. I know that my IE uses some proxy server with port 8080.

I want to connect to my home PC using RDP. I changed RDP server port to 443 but still cant get through.

What would be a practical way to discover an opened outbound port?

Comment: i just want to read my personal emails. mobile internet sucks in the uk. what the hell i am supposed to do. please concentrate on the question rather than spindoctoring. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you can surf the web, but not access webmail.  This sounds like the proxy is also doing web filtering and may be blocking the connection to your PC at home based on a blacklist of common dynamic DNS services or may be setup for whitelist only.

Either way trying to get around IT policy is often grounds for termination.  You may have a shot of getting this to work if you talk with the IT administrator.

Short of the requirement to use RDP you might be able to use Logmein to access your home PC remotely.

Comment: logmein is blocked too

Answer (score 4):

You can't and you shouldn't be sidestepping IT policies. Ask your administrator to set it up.

Comment: i also steal candies from babies

Answer (score 3):

Use Steve Gibson's [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) to do a port scan.

It's true that you are taking the risk of being caught by your network administrator.
People have been fired for such actions, being branded as hackers.

Comment: *being branded as hackers* or just not doing the work they were paid to do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using TeamViewer to get out to your home PC?
That way you can do all the non work related stuff you want ;-)
It can run as a non installable app too if you can;t install it on your work PC.

-- IT Police warning --
this could lead to disciplinary procedures, please use this advice carefully. If you are very naughty then Santa will not bring you any presents and your nose will turn green and fall off. Also you run the risk of disciplinary action for violating what looks like company IT policy.